# Exclude class or package inside classpath when starting an application

Tags: java, classpath

I have multiple `*.jar` files inside a folder, that are all included in the classpath in order to start the specified main class in Microsoft Windows OS.  This is currently accomplished like this:

```
@echo off
java -Xmx1024M -cp libs/*;. org.test.Main
```

Now I have the problem, that inside the `libs` folder there are two JAR files, that both have one same package `org.test.configuration`.  Both are different and when I now start the program, I get errors because the wrong one is selected by the Java VM.

How can I exclude one special Package or one special Class within my start script?  (Of course I could delete this package out of the wrong jar, but I do not want to use this method...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java searches the class path for packages/classes in order.  Instead of using a wildcard ...

```
java -Xmx1024M -cp libs/*;. org.test.Main
```

... write out the class path in the order desired, with the jar containing the "correct" `org.test.configuration` package first.

```
java -Xmx1024M -cp libs/test-config.jar;libs/other.jar;libs/etc.jar;. org.test.Main
```

***Edit***

You might be able to get away still using the wildcard, by just explicitly listing the desired jar first, and letting it get duplicated in the classpath:

```
java -Xmx1024M -cp libs/test-config.jar;libs/*;. org.test.Main
```

---

Here is a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

org\test\Main.java (in main.jar):

```
package org.test;

import org.test.configuration.Config;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Config cfg = Config.getConfig();
        System.out.println(cfg);
    }
}
```

org\test\configuration\Config.java (in config1.jar):

```
package org.test.configuration;

public class Config {
    public static Config getConfig() {
        return new Config();
    }
}
```

org\test\configuration\Config.java (in config2.jar):

```
package org.test.configuration;

public class Config {
    public static Config getConfig() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

> java -cp libs\*;. org.test.Main
>   org.test.configuration.Config@1540e19d
>
> java -cp libs\config2.jar;libs\*;. org.test.Main
>   null

Using just `libs\*` in the classpath resulted in config1.jar being included first, and a live `Config` object was returned.  Using `libs\config2.jar;libs\*` resulted in `Config` from config2.jar being included first, and `null` was returned.

Comment: I already tried this but unfortunately without success. I tried putting the config.jar before the other one and also the other way around. But it is only the false jar loaded. I of course checked that the config class is in both jar files in the same package. and the wrong one is returning a NULL object, so I can test is. And when I then start the server, I always get a NullpointerException. Would java use the other config class, there would be a full functioning object to work with. But java only loads the wrong one ...

Comment: I've added a [mcve], showing that changing the order of jars on the classpath does affect which jar/package is used by the JVM if multiple jars contain different implementations of the same package/classes.  There must be some other factor causing your problem.

Comment: I found my problem: the "real" config JAR file was not included in the maven `pom.xml`. The resulting JAR files both had the config class, but all other projects included the wrong config class as dependency. So although I brought the "real" config class in the classpath, the wrong one was still used. it seems, that maven still pays attention to the pom.xml, even after building the jar file. Because when I add the correct one as dependency as well, we is doing exactly what you are saying :) ... but still I am skeptical. So am I correct with this observation?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing your maven `pom.xml` file.  Maven dependencies are often just compile time dependencies.  They are added to the path during building, just to ensure that external references are valid.  But Maven can also unpack dependency jars, and repackage them into the resulting jars.  Another thing to investigate would be the jar's `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, which might have the dependency jars explicitly listed in the [Class-Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)